# Proof of distance of point in 3 space to line.

Tags: geometry

A line contains the point $p$ and has direction $u$. For any point in space, $q$, it is claimed that this formula finds the distance from the line to $q$. I would like to prove this formula
$$
d=\frac{\|(q-p)\times u\|}{\|u\|}
$$
Please help.

**Editor Context:** This formula is commonly used, but often stated without proof. Using it is easier than having to minimize $\|p-(q+tu)\|$.

[(original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Ujs.jpg)

Comment: Consider http://onlinemschool.com/math/library/analytic_geometry/p_line/

Comment: You might have mentioned that the line is qquestion is $\{\,\mathbf p+t\mathbf u\mid t\in\mathbb R\,\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left((q-p)-\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u\right)\cdot u=0$. Therefore,
$$
(q-p)=\overbrace{\left((q-p)-\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u\right)}^{\perp\,u}+\overbrace{\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u}^{\parallel\,u}
$$
Therefore,
$$
q=\overbrace{\left((q-p)-\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u\right)}^{\text{perpendicular to the line}}+\overbrace{p+\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u}^{\text{on the line}}
$$
Thus, the perpendicular distance from the line is the length of
$$
\left((q-p)-\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u\right)
$$
since this is perpendicular to $u$, its length is
$$
\begin{align}
\left\|\left((q-p)-\frac{(q-p)\cdot u}{\|u\|^2}u\right)\times\frac{u}{\|u\|}\right\|
&=\left\|(q-p)\times\frac{u}{\|u\|}\right\|\\
&=\frac{\|(q-p)\times u\|}{\|u\|}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thx, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Write $\mathbf q=\mathbf s+\mathbf r$ where $s$ is on the line and $\mathbf r\perp\mathbf s$ (by which $d=\|\mathbf r\|$). Then $(\mathbf q-\mathbf p)\times\mathbf u=(\mathbf s-\mathbf p)\times\mathbf u+\mathbf r\times \mathbf u$.